# How to set dynamic value for horizontal line in annotation plugin for Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

Currently have horizontal lines (3) on a Chart.js stacked bar chart using the Annotations plugin [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation).  The values are initially set in the chart options (with values that are not values of points in the chart), but after new chart data is pushed onto the dataset, new values for the three horizontal lines also need to pushed.

The option settings for one of the horizontal lines:

```
  annotation: {
    annotations: [{
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-1',
      value: 75;
      borderColor: color(window.chartColors.green).alpha(0.7).rgbString(),
      label: {
        enabled: true,
        content: 'Label 1'
      }
    }]
  }
```

How can new values be set for the position of those lines?

(If unable to do so, will likely just define two sets of chart options with the respective values and destroy the first and replace with the second when the update is needed.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Found it!
    `myChart.options.annotation.annotations[].value`